# Cannot get NLog to write to disc on the server

Tags: nlog, asp.net-core-webapi

I can write to NLog on my local machine, but when I deploy to the server it fails.

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        app.AddNLogWeb();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
        SetAutomapper();
        try
        {
            var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("Started Properties Web API");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
```

The above code is in my Web API Core project, Startup class.
The error message is

```
SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

I use the standard Stored Procedure to write to NLog;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p] (
  @machineName nvarchar(200),
  @siteName nvarchar(200),
  @logged datetime,
  @level varchar(5),
  @userName nvarchar(200),
  @message nvarchar(max),
  @logger nvarchar(300),
  @properties nvarchar(max),
  @serverName nvarchar(200),
  @port nvarchar(100),
  @url nvarchar(2000),
  @https bit,
  @serverAddress nvarchar(100),
  @remoteAddress nvarchar(100),
  @callSite nvarchar(300),
  @exception nvarchar(max)
) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[SIR_NLog] (
    [MachineName],
    [SiteName],
    [Logged],
    [Level],
    [UserName],
    [Message],
    [Logger],
    [Properties],
    [ServerName],
    [Port],
    [Url],
    [Https],
    [ServerAddress],
    [RemoteAddress],
    [CallSite],
    [Exception]
  ) VALUES (
    @machineName,
    @siteName,
    @logged,
    @level,
    @userName,
    @message,
    @logger,
    @properties,
    @serverName,
    @port,
    @url,
    @https,
    @serverAddress,
    @remoteAddress,
    @callSite,
    @exception
  );
END
```

So the issue here is that the Logged parameter field must be sent a string rather than a date. Why would this be?

EDIT: My NLog.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">
  <!-- throwExceptions="true"-->

  <!-- Load the ASP.NET Core plugin -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <target name="db"
            xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="${var:SirNLogDb}"
            commandType="StoredProcedure"
            commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]">
      <parameter name="@machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@siteName"       layout="${iis-site-name}" />
      <parameter name="@logged"         layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level"          layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@username"       layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
      <parameter name="@message"        layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@logger"         layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
      <parameter name="@serverName"     layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
      <parameter name="@port"           layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
      <parameter name="@url"            layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
      <parameter name="@https"          layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />
      <parameter name="@serverAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
      <parameter name="@remoteAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite"       layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@exception"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="db" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Please post your NLog config

Comment: SQL Server is probably not recognizing it as a date even though it is. You might have to format it in your layout like ${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem I found was that the regional date settings were different on each server. One was US English and the other was British.
The easiest solution for this case was to remove the @logged parameter and just use GetDate() instead to get the current date.
There is probably a better solution. The SQL Servers should both have the same date settings but I am not sure what the knock on effects of that will be.